# How to parse "streamed" json objects with json4s?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a streaming source that produces many JSON objects without separators (or only whitespace in between). If I pass that to json4s `parse` function, it only produces AST for the first object.

As a workaround, I could parse it manually and either turn it into a JSON array by adding brackets and commas as appropriate or chunk it and call `parse` on each chunk.

However, this is a [rather common format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON), so I'm sure the problem is already solved. I just cannot find the API for it in json4s documentation.

Comment: jawn seems to support this via `ValueStream`. jhttps://index.scala-lang.org/non/jawn/jawn-parser - if you want a proper stream processing with it: https://github.com/circe/circe-fs2 - decode with circe.

Comment: @Reactormonk, I'm not really enthusiastic about adding another json library dependency, but jawn can produce json4s AST so I won't rule it out if there's no support for this in json4s itself.

Comment: I've found circe codecs to be more maintainable than the manual codecs by json4s.

Comment: @Reactormonk, no need for manual codecs with json4s and case classes, it least in my use case. Honestly, I have no idea how it actually works under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If you reading it from an `InputStream`, then use `BufferedInputStream` wrapper with `mark()`, `read()` and `reset()` calls to skip whitespace(s) between `parse()` call:

```
val in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/tmp/your.json"))
try {
  var continue = true
  in.mark(1)
  do {
    in.reset()         

    // <-- here should be call for parse

    // skip white spaces or exit if EOF found
    var b = 0
    do {
      in.mark(1)
      b = in.read()
      if (b < 0) continue = false
    } while (Character.isWhitespace(b))
  } while (continue)
} finally in.close()
```

EDIT: Today I have released [0.11.0 version of jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/releases/tag/v0.11.0) with new ability to parse streaming JSON values or JSON arrays w/o need to hold all values in memory.

Comment: That is pretty much what I meant by chunking it manually (well, plus some type gymnastics to get an input stream). I was hoping there is support for this within json4s.